# Does moveIt monitor the planned path for validity?

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I have a setup with a robot-arm and 3D-Sensors observing the workspace. I want the arm to execute some Pick & Place scenarios, while I move through the workspace.
Now, while planning the octomap gets respected, the created plans avoid any collisions.
But my question is, would moveIt check if an obstacle moved into the planned path, therefore making it invalid?
[Here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/moveit-users/%7B7e3c67eb-4a87-46b2-8b32-91f71c78abda%7D20avoidance/moveit-users/osxc3aRlEHw/hBhsvfq_6JQJ) I read about the StateValidity-Service, but I am wondering if I have to implement it myself or if it happens automaticly?

Thanks in advance,
Rabe

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192839/does-moveit-monitor-the-planned-path-for-validity?/) by [Rabe](https://answers.ros.org/users/15571/rabe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 683 on 2014-09-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After setting everything up properly, MoveIt calls the necessary Actions to preempt any executions whenever an obstacle moves into the space.
If replanning is activated, it'll wait 2 seconds and then start planning again for the same target.

---

Originally posted by [Rabe](https://answers.ros.org/users/15571/rabe/) with karma: 683 on 2014-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0